# Will switching from Oracle Java to OpenJDK to avoid paying from Jan 2019 work

Tags: java

I have couple of projects using JDK 1.8 in production. However Java is paid from January 2019 onwards. Is my problem solved if I migrate my projects to OpenJDK 1.8 because it's open source?

Comment: I think you don't really understand what's going to happen. the new versions of Java will be paid, but not necessarily. if you don't immediately update to the latest updates/versions, but wait a while, you'll still be able to use Java free. It's security/support/free usage. One of these three you'll have to sacrifice

Comment: as for your Java 8, it'll still be free. It's the newest version that might cost a price.

Comment: @Stultuske I actually understood that differently: for all I know, the change only targets Java 8 for now, and it seems to be about updates and support after Jan 2019. Considering there are and will be later versions available, maybe the only step required would be to migrate to Java x > 8? I have to admit that the news I've read so far are awfully confusing though.

Comment: Some information from Oracle [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/documentation/eol-135779.html).

Comment: I've read three articles describing it (more or less) the way I explained it. Oracle is following angular: they're going to release a new Major version of Java every few months, instead of the current pace (which takes years for a new major version to be released and somewhat widely adopted), that is supposed to be a part of the strategy: if you pay, you get the latest security updates of the latest version, and you get support. 
If you wait with installing the latest updates, you should still be able to use it free of charge, but you'll risk not having access to the latest security updates)

Comment: So, I understand if I retain the same version of java I use in production which is `jdk1.8.0_131` and not update, then there is no need for any change. Only new updates or newer version will be charged ?

Comment: @Mena thanks for the link. as it states there, it's only starting from JDK11 that the OpenJDK will be the alternative. I don't see them saying anywhere they're going to charge for Java 8, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java is no longer free for commerical use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130476/java-is-no-longer-free-for-commerical-use)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, it concerns **only the Oracle Java APIs**.

**OpenJDK** and **OpenJFX** are largely independent (besides getting contributions from Oracle).

As general Oracle Java was a bit smarter than the OpenJDK (on Linux), the entire outcries are a storm in a glass of water: it makes a (ill guided) sense to let Oracle be paid for its development effort.

The thing to do, is trying out the OpenJDK, and taking notion of **com.sun** classes.

You might need to look for new versions of your typical server or framework, that might rely on `com.sun.*` classes.